# How to cite the Ethereum Yellow Paper in a scientific work

Tags: yellow-paper

Maybe the question can be off-topic or more appropriate for other communities, I try to ask it here.

I am currently writing my thesis and I want to cite the yellow paper. Google scholar provides the original version of 2014:

```
@article{wood2014ethereum,
     title={Ethereum: A secure decentralised generalised transaction ledger},
     author={Wood, Gavin},
     journal={Ethereum project yellow paper},
     volume={151},
     pages={1--32},
     year={2014}
 }
```

I would like to cite the current version (or at least a recent one).

Where can I found the information about journal and volume and It is still correct to indicate Gavin Wood as the **only** Author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow paper wasn't published in a scientific journal and it was authored by Gavin wood. To cite the current version you can reference :

Link: https://gavwood.com/paper.pdf or   https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper

as you see google indicates that this link was referenced in many scientific papers :

[image]

and here is a list of paper referencing the yellow paper in google scholar:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?client=firefox-b-ab&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&q=related:cxfupOECevEHQM:scholar.google.com/

BibTeX format:

```
@article{wood2014ethereum,
  title={Ethereum: A secure decentralised generalised transaction ledger},
  author={Wood, Gavin and others},
  journal={Ethereum project yellow paper},
  volume={151},
  number={2014},
  pages={1--32},
  year={2014}
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but the version is too old and super-deprecated, I would like to cite the current one. Obviously, all authors cite the old version but actually use the most recent one. BTW the bibtex entry I cited is the one taken from google scholar, as I said in the question :)

Comment: if you have looked at the github repos i ve shared in my answer, you would find the latest version https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf. you'll find all details in their readme file

Comment: You are right, but they do not provide how to cite their work :/ Thank you for the answer ^^

Comment: just use there url and author's name. If you think the link is enough please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The paper does not contain any information about journal of any sort, nor year of publishing. The critical information is the version/revision.

According to the citebay: http://citebay.com/how-to-cite/ethereum/

I would use one of following:

**Version of paper as edition**

```
@article{wood2014ethereum,
     title={Ethereum: A secure decentralised generalised transaction ledger},
     author={Wood, Gavin},
     edition={EIP-150 REVISION}
}
```

**Version of paper in name**

```
@article{wood2014ethereum,
     title={Ethereum: A secure decentralised generalised transaction ledger EIP-150 REVISION},
     author={Wood, Gavin},
}
```

I would use the version that works better with the final citation norm I use.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  EIP-150 is not a revision or version of the yellow paper; it's an Ethereum improvement proposal.